# Issues reading from json (kendo ui)

Tags: php, json, kendo-ui

my boss told me to test kendo ui especially scheduler reading from json. For test purpose i wrote a php file for the json output:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type:application/json");

$cars = array
    (
        0 => array(
                                'Id'=>'DN-DP-1596',
                                'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
                                'Description'=>'Appoinment with Acme Inc.',
                                'StartTimeZone'=>null,
                                'Start'=>'2016/1/12 07:00 AM',
                                'End'=>'2016/1/12 09:00 AM',
                                'EndTimeZone'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceID'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceException'=>null,
                                'IsAllDay'=>false
            ),
        1 => array(
                                'Id'=>'DN-UQ-1503',
                                'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
                                'Description'=>'Appoinment with Bauer GmbH.',
                                'StartTimeZone'=>null,
                                'Start'=>'2016/1/12 09:30 AM',
                                'End'=>'2016/1/12 10:30 AM',
                                'EndTimeZone'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceID'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceException'=>null,
                                'IsAllDay'=>false
            ),
        2 => array(
                                'Id'=>'DN-VH-791',
                                'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
                                'Description'=>'Trading conference',
                                'StartTimeZone'=>null,
                                'Start'=>'2016/1/12 01:00 PM',
                                'End'=>'2016/1/12 03:00 PM',
                                'EndTimeZone'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceID'=>null,
                                'RecurrenceException'=>null,
                                'IsAllDay'=>false
            )
    );
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
print $callback.'('.json_encode($cars).')';
```

Then I wrote some html to test the kendo Scheduler:

```
    <div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
    $("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({ date: new Date("2016/1/13") });
    var scheduler = $("#scheduler").data("kendoScheduler");
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource
    ({
        transport:
        {
          read:
          {
              url:"carService.php",
              dataType:"jsonp"                  
          }
        }

    });
    dataSource.fetch(function()
    {
        var cars = dataSource.data();
        var dataItem = dataSource.get(0);

        console.log(dataItem.Title);
    })
```

Unfortunately I do not get a console output or anything else, any ideas about this? help is very appreciated, my boss is terrorizing me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with same code and made minor changes in code. have a look on below code.

**test.html**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.common.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.silver.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/styles/kendo.mobile.all.min.css"/>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.1.112/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
    var dataSource = new kendo.data.SchedulerDataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "test.php",
                dataType: "jsonp"
            }
        }
    });
    dataSource.fetch(function () {
        var event = this.at(0);
        console.log(event.Title);
    });
</script>
```

**test.php** - For json data

```
<?php
$cars = array
(
    0 => array(
        'Id'=>'DN-DP-1596',
        'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
        'Description'=>'Appoinment with Acme Inc.',
        'StartTimeZone'=>null,
        'Start'=>'2016/1/12 07:00 AM',
        'End'=>'2016/1/12 09:00 AM',
        'EndTimeZone'=>null,
        'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
        'RecurrenceID'=>null,
        'RecurrenceException'=>null,
        'IsAllDay'=>false
    ),
    1 => array(
        'Id'=>'DN-UQ-1503',
        'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
        'Description'=>'Appoinment with Bauer GmbH.',
        'StartTimeZone'=>null,
        'Start'=>'2016/1/12 09:30 AM',
        'End'=>'2016/1/12 10:30 AM',
        'EndTimeZone'=>null,
        'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
        'RecurrenceID'=>null,
        'RecurrenceException'=>null,
        'IsAllDay'=>false
    ),
    2 => array(
        'Id'=>'DN-VH-791',
        'Title'=>'Business Trip to Cologne',
        'Description'=>'Trading conference',
        'StartTimeZone'=>null,
        'Start'=>'2016/1/12 01:00 PM',
        'End'=>'2016/1/12 03:00 PM',
        'EndTimeZone'=>null,
        'RecurrenceRule'=>null,
        'RecurrenceID'=>null,
        'RecurrenceException'=>null,
        'IsAllDay'=>false
    )
);
$callback = $_GET['callback'];
print $callback.'('.json_encode($cars).')';
```

**output at console:**

```
Business Trip to Cologne
```

So all you need to change in php file while echoing json output.

Comment: thk u so far, but when I change the php code like this I dont get a json output anymore. Instead there seems some html tag stuff then.

Comment: I think u are right, but I dont know how to use it. I watched some example json from kendo and they begin with callback(...) , what am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is output of json?

Comment: can you try after removing `header("Content-Type:application/json");`

Comment: if I remove the header()-line i get a undefined index exception

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100566/discussion-between-ismir-wumpe-and-chetan-ameta).